# How to use start on multiple commands in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, windows-10

Is it possible to make CMD `start` run more than one command on its new thread? I tried this:

```
:: Use start to finish before we're deleted
start /min (
    :: Do some work...
    :: Remove the app's root folder
    rd /s /q %~dp0
)
```

But I'm getting "Windows cannot find the file `)`. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again."

Is there any way around this without creating a new batch script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `cmd /c "........"` with `&` to separate the commands.

- start a new minimized console window

  ```c
  start /min "window title" cmd /c "action1 & action2 >logfile.txt & action3"
  ```

  When omitting the outer quotes make sure to escape the special characters like `<`, `>`, `&`, `|`:

  ```c
  start /min "" cmd /c action1 ^& action2 "some parameter" ^>"logfile.txt" ^& action3
  ```

  When using the outer quotes repeat the inner quotes three times:

  ```c
  start /min "" cmd /c "action1 & action2 >"""some logfile.txt""" & action3"
  ```
- start a new process in the current console window:

  ```c
  start /b "" cmd /c ......
  ```
- an example of multiline syntax for improved readability:

  ```c
  start /min "" cmd /c ^
      dir r:\ %= inline comment =% ^& ^
      echo 2 ^>r:\2 ^& ^
      %= inline comment =% ^
      pause
  ```

Comment: One of the ugliest, yep.

Comment: You should be able to put all the commands on one line and surround them all with quotes.

Comment: Indeed, it's useful. I've added the examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm - In the last code example, does this mean there must be an executable for `r:\2` such as `2.exe` or `2.bat`?

Comment: @Liturgist, output of `echo` is redirected to a file `r:\2`